# PHP calendar needs to start week with sunday

Tags: php, datetime, calendar

I have a script but it is not what I need(Start every week with Sunday without bug). modify("-1 days") or modify("+6 days") shows what I need but sometimes it results in previous week or next week accordingly.
I have searched a lot for the solution but could not get it.
Need some help.

Code:

```
<?php 

$dt = new DateTime;
if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['week'])) {
    $dt->setISODate($_GET['year'], $_GET['week']);
} else {
    $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
}
$year = $dt->format('o');
$week = $dt->format('W');
/*$dt->modify("-1 days");*/ // This -1 or +6 will make it starts with sunday but sometimes it shows the wrong week.
?>

<div class="next-pre">
<div class="pre-week float-left">
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Pre Week</a>
</div>

<div class="next-week float-right">
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Next Week</a>
</div>
</div>

<?php
$numDay = 1;
do {

?>
      <div class="calender">
        <table class="weeks">
          <tr>
<?php if($dt->format('d M Y') == date('d M Y')){ ?>
            <td class="color cell"><?php echo $dt->format('l'); ?>   <strong class="margin5"> <?php echo $dt->format('d M Y'); ?> </strong></td>
            <td class="default cell"> </td>
<?php } else{ ?>
            <td class="default cell"><?php echo $dt->format('l'); ?>   <strong class="margin5"> <?php echo $dt->format('d M Y');  ?> </strong></td>
            <td class="default cell"> </td>
<?php } ?>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

<?php
/*echo "<td>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</td>\n";*/
    $dt->modify('+1 days');
    $numDay++;

} while ($numDay<=7);

?>
```

Comment: For PHP versions `5.6.23, 7.0.8: [Weeks always start on monday. Formerly, sunday would also be considered to start a week.][1]` [1]:http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

So, if you upgraded your php version, your problem should be solved

Comment: Or use the IntlCalendar: http://php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.setfirstdayofweek.php