# PHP Calendar - start week on Sunday

Tags: php

I am building a calendar using PHP/jQuery AJAX based on [this tutorial](https://phppot.com/jquery/creating-web-calendar-in-php-using-jquery-ajax/) I found. It works great, except that I would like to modify it so that the week starts on Sunday. I have updated the weekday labels but I am struggling to figure out how to change the logic that actually builds the calendar to match the new order of the labels. I tried adjusting the `$this->currentMonthStart` to use the 2nd day of the month:

`$this->currentMonthStart = $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-02';`

which actually does produce the desired result for the current month(February), but it throws off the dates for future months. I also tried the following:

```
$firstDayOfTheWeek = date ( 'N', strtotime ( "+1 day", strtotime($this->currentMonthStart)) );
```

But I think that's the same as changing the `currentMonthStart` to the 2nd, so it results in the same issue.

Is there a way to globally tell the constructor to start on Sunday?

```
<?php
class PHPCalendar {
    // Original weekday labels
    // private $weekDayName = array ("MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT","SUN");
    
    // New weekday labels with Sunday as the start day
    private $weekDayName = array ("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT");
    private $currentDay = 0;
    private $currentMonth = 0;
    private $currentYear = 0;
    private $currentMonthStart = null;
    private $currentMonthDaysLength = null; 
    
    function __construct() {
        $this->currentYear = date ( "Y", time () );
        $this->currentMonth = date ( "m", time () );
        
        if (! empty ( $_POST ['year'] )) {
            $this->currentYear = $_POST ['year'];
        }
        if (! empty ( $_POST ['month'] )) {
            $this->currentMonth = $_POST ['month'];
        }
        $this->currentMonthStart = $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-01';
        $this->currentMonthDaysLength = date ( 't', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
    }
    
    function getCalendarHTML() {
        $calendarHTML = '<div id="calendar-outer">'; 
        $calendarHTML .= '<div class="calendar-nav">' . $this->getCalendarNavigation() . '</div>'; 
        $calendarHTML .= '<ul class="week-name-title">' . $this->getWeekDayName () . '</ul>';
        $calendarHTML .= '<ul class="week-day-cell">' . $this->getWeekDays () . '</ul>';        
        $calendarHTML .= '</div>';
        return $calendarHTML;
    }
    
    function getCalendarNavigation() {
        $prevMonthYear = date ( 'm,Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart. ' -1 Month'  ) );
        $prevMonthYearArray = explode(",",$prevMonthYear);
        
        $nextMonthYear = date ( 'm,Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart . ' +1 Month'  ) );
        $nextMonthYearArray = explode(",",$nextMonthYear);
        
        $navigationHTML = '<div class="prev" data-prev-month="' . $prevMonthYearArray[0] . '" data-prev-year = "' . $prevMonthYearArray[1]. '"><</div>'; 
        $navigationHTML .= '<span id="currentMonth">' . date ( 'M ', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) ) . '</span>';
        $navigationHTML .= '<span contenteditable="true" id="currentYear">'.    date ( 'Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) ) . '</span>';
        $navigationHTML .= '<div class="next" data-next-month="' . $nextMonthYearArray[0] . '" data-next-year = "' . $nextMonthYearArray[1]. '">></div>';
        return $navigationHTML;
    }
    
    function getWeekDayName() {
        $WeekDayName= '';       
        foreach ( $this->weekDayName as $dayname ) {            
            $WeekDayName.= '<li>' . $dayname . '</li>';
        }       
        return $WeekDayName;
    }
    
    function getWeekDays() {
        $weekLength = $this->getWeekLengthByMonth ();
        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
        $weekDays = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $weekLength; $i ++) {
            for($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j ++) {
                $cellIndex = $i * 7 + $j;
                $cellValue = null;
                if ($cellIndex == $firstDayOfTheWeek) {
                    $this->currentDay = 1;
                }
                if (! empty ( $this->currentDay ) && $this->currentDay <= $this->currentMonthDaysLength) {
                    $cellValue = $this->currentDay;
                    $this->currentDay ++;
                }
                $weekDays .= '<li>' . $cellValue . '</li>';
            }
        }
        return $weekDays;
    }
    
    function getWeekLengthByMonth() {
        $weekLength =  intval ( $this->currentMonthDaysLength / 7 );    
        if($this->currentMonthDaysLength % 7 > 0) {
            $weekLength++;
        }
        $monthStartDay= date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart) );        
        $monthEndingDay= date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-' . $this->currentMonthDaysLength) );
        if ($monthEndingDay < $monthStartDay) {         
            $weekLength++;
        }
        
        return $weekLength;
    }
}
?>
```

Here's how the calendar currently looks:
[image]

And here's what I would like it to look like:
[image]

Comment: I believe it's a locale-specific setting whether the week starts on Monday or Sunday. Here, it's Monday, but in other parts of the world it's Sunday. So, search for locale-specific settings for the start of the week. If that doesn't work, implement your own. Concerning your code and the problem you have with it, it's not completely clear. Please provide a [mcve] to clarify.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt but the date is always going to land on the same day of the week no matter where you are in the world. Currently Thursday, February 1st is in the 4th column on this calendar, I am trying to move it to the 5th.

Comment: When I Googled `php start week on sunday`, I found MANY pre-existing pages on Stack Overflow.  Did you find anything useful / not useful while searching?  Please show us the pages that you've already read so that we don't recommend them to you again.

Comment: Topically Relevant: [PHP calendar needs to start week with sunday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43300574/2943403)

Comment: @mickmackusa So far I've found [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-first-day-of-week-in-php#:~:text=php%20echo%20%22Displaying%20Sunday%20as,%22%2C%20%24res%3B%20%3F%3E) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057039/how-to-get-weeks-starting-on-sunday) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php) but anything I've tried has resulted in the same sort of issues as when I tried setting `currentMonthStart` to the 2nd. I can typically get Feburary to display correctly, but then when I go to March it only has 30 days instead of 31.

Comment: I tried `$firstDayOfTheWeek = date ( 'N', strtotime ( "+1 day", strtotime($this->currentMonthStart)) );` but that results in the same issue as above